# Reversing the order of letters/characters of a selected region

Tags: region

How can one reverse the letters/characters in a selected region?

xyz --> zyx

ab cde --> edc ba

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Emacs doesn't seem to provide any function to do this out of the box, but implementing one isn't that hard:

```
(defun my-reverse-region (beg end)
 "Reverse characters between BEG and END."
 (interactive "r")
 (let ((region (buffer-substring beg end)))
   (delete-region beg end)
   (insert (nreverse region))))
```

Comment: Perfect, works well.

Comment: Mark my answer as an solution if it helped you.

Comment: Of course. Usually I wait for a while for alternative solutions, then mark it as accepted.

Comment: You can also use `delete-and-extract-region`, i.e., `(insert (nreverse (delete-and-extract-region beg end)))`.

Comment: How do you use it with `Meta + x`? If I highlight a region (e.g. the `abc` string) and then execute it, I get the following error: `Wrong type argument: listp, #("abc" 0 3 (fontified t))`

Comment: @tonix can you try with `emacs -q`?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 Should I run it in terminal when starting emacs?

Answer (score 1):

Since emacs can call the shell on a region of text,
and since [shell can reverse text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24134488)
I believe there's an alternative/elegant(?) solution to the OPs problem,.

> That's a comment but not an answer

okay how about

```
    ;; select the region, then
    C-u M-|
    ;; Shell command on region:
    rev<enter>
```

Comment: ... although it reverses lines, not the region.